# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes after login on wayland

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, wayland

Just upgraded from 17.04.
Unity session works. Ubuntu (gnome-shell) on xorg works too.
If I select the default session (Ubuntu on Wayland), after the password, the screen becomes purple, the mouse cursor freezes in the center of the screen and I can't do anything than power off with a single click on the power button.

Don't know if this can help, but after login in Unity session, a dialog error appears, saying

**required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1,1), minum=(320,200), maximum=(8192,8192)**

Obviously it didn't appear on 17.04.

How can I investigate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a gnome-shell extension (freon) that was causing the freeze in my case. Log into gnome with xorg, disable all your gnome-shell extensions and try to log back into gnome (with wayland).

If it works then try to re-enable your gnome-shell extensions one by one. In my case when I enabled the freon extension everything froze...

Comment: After I did what the previous answer suggested, Ubuntu with Xorg won't start: it brings me back to login as Wayland does.

Comment: You were right. Prime Switch indicator was to be blamed!

Answer (score 3):

If your running on an nvidia card, I have just encountered this issue.

Booting to a recovery console, purging the nvidia drivers and reinstalling was sufficient for me to rectify the issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 (in my case)
```

Comment: I'm running on a intel integrated card
yes I'm also a discrete nvidia card but it's powered off by default

Comment: anyway, doing as suggested changes not much: after the password, I'm redirected again to the login page...

Answer (score 0):

I had been setting my pointer speed to the slowest it could be in Unity, in Ubuntu 17.04. Then I upgraded to 17.10. After I log into the default session, my mouse cursor could not move anymore. Then I changed the pointer speed to be a little higher, and the cursor worked normally.

Perhaps that will solve the problem for you as well. **If your mouse sensitivity is set very low, even if it worked before on that setting, increase it a little and see if cursor can be moved.**

I think if we set the pointer speed to slowest, the new session will multiply my pointer speed by a zero. (Is it a bug?)