# Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME won't start : required virtual size does not fit available size

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, 17.10

After upgrading to 17.10, I had no issue neither with GNOME (which I use the most) on Xorg nor Unity. But once, while on a GNOME session, I wasn't able to open some applications (including Settings) and since then I'm not able to log in to the GNOME session.

### What happens :

- When trying to log in to GNOME (either vanilla GNOME or 'Ubuntu' GNOME, and either on Xorg or Wayland - when it is listed), I enter my password, then I got a black screen for a few seconds and then I'm back on the log in screen.
- When logging in Unity session (which works more or less), I got this error :

  > ### Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors
  >
  > required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1, 1), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(8192, 8192)
- I later noticed that there is many more lines displayed on boot, including several time this kind of errors `Error: Method parse/execution failed ...`, `ACPI Error: [_OSI] Namespace lookup failure`, as well as this line once `Couldn't get size : 0x800000000000000e`

### What I tried :

- I read [this issue (Ubuntu 17.10 freezes after logging on wayland)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966690/ubuntu-17-10-freezes-after-login-on-wayland/966871), but since I can't log on GNOME at all, I wasn't able to disable my extensions to see if it resolved the issue. Removing and reinstalling NVIDIA packages didn't help (I've got a GeForce GT 840M, in addition to Intel default graphics).
- I changed the driver used for the graphic card. I tried both NVIDIA proprietary driver (version 384) and 'X.Org X server', and all that changed was the 'minimum' and 'maximum' size on the error message.
- Since I'm not using any second monitor (I'm on a laptop, so I only have the built-in display), I checked that Ubuntu wasn't trying to connect to another - non existing - display and I see no other display in the System Settings. The settings also tell me that the resolution is the default one (1366x768), so I guess it recognizes correctly the built-in display. I might (probably) be wrong on this last point.
- I, of course, rebooted my system after every try to be sure it had not solved my issue.

Comment: Does it work if you boot 17.10 from a live USB ? Failed upgrades can be difficult and with all the changes .....

Comment: I'll try that (again, I already did it for a completely different issue), but I don't think the upgrade is the cause: it worked well for almost 2 weeks after the upgrade...

Comment: open source or nvidia driver ?

Comment: It worked with both (I had to change from one to the other because of render issue in MATLAB, but I don't remember which). As for the live USB, it works as expected, but I don't know what this fact proves.

Comment: It makes it more likely you have a corrupt config. Try deleting all unity and gnome configuration files and log out and back in.

Comment: What's the "cleanest" way to do that ? (And I'll try on the morrow to report back)

Comment: Try this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: I resetted GNOME as explained, and it now works fine (which is what I wanted the most). I still get the error when logging in Unity, so it seems it's not the same issue, but they came at the same time... weird. I'll reset Unity as well, but I don't use it any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did as @Panther suggested : I reset GNOME as [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults), yet I still had the issue in Unity. As I used mostly GNOME I didn't bothered about Unity, but I eventually made a fresh install of 17.10 for  several other reasons.

Since the issue appeared some time ago I not sure about this, but I seem to remember that it was a Shell Extension that caused the issue. I think it might be *ISS Above*, because I installed it the day I got the issue and I didn't install it back after the reset, but not sure (for anyone who would run in the same issue).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by issuing:

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm && service lightdm restart
```

Maybe the same can solve for gdm

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue after upgrading from 16.10 to 17.10: the gnome session worked, but the unity one kept displaying the *"required virtual size does not fit [...]"* message and my double monitor setup was not being properly handled (monitors were swapped).

I've then had a look at the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file and noticed that it had **changed format**! At its top was now a `<monitors version="`**`2`**`">` string, whilst the previous one had a `<monitors version="`**`1`**`">` string, and the rest of the file showed a completely different layout and tags.

I thus concluded that the message *"required virtual size does not fit [...]"* was being displayed by `unity-settings-daemon` which failed to parse the content of the new `monitors.xml` file.

Adding to that was the fact that the the display panel in the `gnome-control-center` was not working during the Unity session, due to error:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig was not provided by any .service files
```

I therefore installed `unity-control-center`, ran it, and sure enough the Display panel was working and the correct (previous version) `monitor.xml` was being written.

After a reboot, everything worked as expected.

## CONCLUSIONS

The problem seems to be related to a mismatch between the expected `monitor.xml`  and the real one. Unity and Gnome shell write and parse different and incompatible versions of that file, which makes it impossible to seamlessy switch between those two session types.