# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes

Tags: freeze, 17.10

Just upgraded from 17.04. Shortly after logging in the mouse cursor freezes and I can't do anything other than power off or ALT SYSRQ REISUB.

I realize this is a duplicate question, but the solution at [Ubuntu 17.10 freezes after login on wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966690/ubuntu-17-10-freezes-after-login-on-wayland) does not provide enough instruction for me to implement the solution and I don't have the points to ask for further details in a comment.  I need simple instructions.

Comment: Boot from an older kernel at the GRUB menu. Does the problem still occur?

Comment: I think the older stuff got deleted, but the GRUB menu does not appear when I boot up.

Comment: Ubuntu *never* deletes all your old kernels. At least one is still there. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/ for how to find it.

Comment: It did freeze periodically with the previous version but not it freezes every hour or so.  I installed the "flash video fix" so I could watch Hulu.  I wonder if that is the source of the problem.